# ¿Como hago para que no siga si el primer numero es 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Como puedo hacer para que si es 0 el primer numero se acabe y si es otro numero siga con la segunda condicion?
Muchisimas gracias

```
    #Realizamos un programa que lea 3 numeros:
    numero1 = int(input("Introduce el primer numero: "))
    numero2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo numero: "))
    numero3 = int(input("Introduce el tercer numero: "))

    #Creo una tupla con los numeros:
    numeros = (numero1,numero2,numero3)
    print (numeros)

    #Imprimir error si el primer numero es 0
    if numero1 == 0:
    print ("Error, no introducir el numero 0")
   
    #Saber si los numeros estan en orden ascendente:
    if numero1<numero2<numero3:
    print ("El orden de los numeros es ascendente")
    else:
    print ("El orden de los numeros NO es ascendente:")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que los `print` estén dentro de los `if` tienes que hacer una indentación, una tabulación, de lo contrario los `print` se ejecutarán igualmente independientemente de cuál sea la condición.

```
if numero1 == 0:
    print ("Error, no introducir el numero 0")
```

Si quieres que la segunda condición solo se evalue si la primera es falsa debes usar un `elif`

```
if numero1 == 0:
    print ("Error, no introducir el numero 0")
   
elif numero1<numero2<numero3:
    print ("El orden de los numeros es ascendente")

else:
    print ("El orden de los numeros NO es ascendente:")
```

De esta forma se evaluará el primer `if` , si la condición es falsa, pasará al `elif` y si esta también es falsa pasará al `else`. Espero que te ayude :D, si es así puntua la respuesta como correcta para darla por contestada :). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La indentación es importante en Python; te dice hasta donde llega el bloque de instrucciones.

La solución a lo que pides es convertir el primer `if` en un `if-else`.

```
#Imprimir error si el primer numero es 0
if numero1 == 0:
    print ("Error, no introducir el numero 0")
else:
    #Saber si los numeros estan en orden ascendente:
    if numero1<numero2<numero3:
        print ("El orden de los numeros es ascendente")
    else:
        print ("El orden de los numeros NO es ascendente:")
```